# TailwindCSS GRID

Tags: html, css, reactjs, tailwindcss, tailwind

как через tailwind сделать такое отображение блоков? мне нужно использовать grid стили

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Сначала учимся жить без приблуд, учим нативный css  тем более что он все приколы умеет а потом используем тайлвинт или что душе угодно